# Why have a shutdown port in Tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I am trying to think of a reason why Tomcat would have a shutdown port but I can't think of any. As I understand it this port only works if messaged locally as it's attached to the loopback device, hence what's the point of having this? Couldn't this be done via internal command in a way that couldn't be spoofed by someone from outside your network?

Thank you!

Comment: *Could* it have been done differently? Yes! *Has* it been done differently? No! Who cares? It's what the shutdown command connects to in order to terminate the server.

Comment: I care. If one form is more secure than other, then why go for the most insecure?

Comment: @OlafKock thank you for the very constructive comment anyway.

Comment: Well, listening on the loopback adapter for some message that can't be spoofed by someone from outside your network sounds a lot like what you desire. Thus I don't see any security implications. If you can demonstrate that thus is an attack vector, you might want to discuss this with tomcat's developers, but I see nothing here that looks like a mild threat. Thus my choice of words "who cares?" - it was not a real question and I hope it didn't offend

Comment: I wasn't offended. But sometimes I feel that people like to excuse poor design decisions without giving any real justification. I don't know if it can really be spoofed as I haven't tried. But I know that in [Tomcat's security Considerations page](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html) it is advised you disable Why recommend this if there was no possibility of external attack? and, why not having disabled by default then?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The shutdown port provides an OS neutral, scriptable way to shutdown a Tomcat instance. Once you remove the shutdown port you are almost certainly into the realms of OS specific code (or at least different code for Windows vs Unix plus derivatives). By default, Tomcat aims for common configuration and behaviour across all platforms.

The security profile of Tomcat installations vary wildly from single developer machines to thousands of instances in the cloud. It is impossible for the default configuration to be perfect for all likely installation environments. Tomcat aims for reasonably secure defaults that admins are expected to adjust to suit their environment.

In this case, the security risks come if untrusted users a) have access to the shutdown port and b) know the shutdown command. This should be a fairly rare scenario, hence why the shutdown port remains enabled for localhost by default. I certainly wouldn't want to run a service where I cared about its security on a machine where I had untrusted users. That said it does happen and, for those use cases, the shutdown port can be disabled.

Once the shutdown port is disabled, the Unix + derivatives solution is to set TOMCAT_PID at which point the scripts will continue to work as expected. On Windows, you are proably going to need to run as a service.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find more parameters that can be passed to the server container [here](http://www.techpaste.com/2012/01/server-xml-container-configurations-tomcat-7-explained/).

Aside from the default, you can also pass the `address` attribute which would allow you to specify where Tomcat can be shut down from, which makes more sense that way.

However I still feel (given there doesn't seem to be a reason why not to) that it should be disabled by default.